# Are generic methods required to have a generic type parameter to work correctly?

Tags: java, generics, zk

I'm just going over some classes trying to generify the code to modernise it somewhat, and I've noticed that there is a library method that is used quite commonly in my classes that seems to be fundamentally wrong, but I don't feel I have the knowledge to quite explain whether it is actually wrong or not.

We use ListModel's from a Java Web UI Framework called ZK for our data retrieved from database tables and then shown in Listboxes, and I noticed there is a lot of code that does something along the lines of:

```
ListModelList lm = (ListModelList) lbox.getListModel();
lm.add(item);
```

The library method declaration for "getListModel()" is:

```
public <T> ListModel<T> getListModel()
```

and can be found here: http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Listbox.html#getListModel()

Now when I put do this:

```
ListModelList<Material> lm = new ListModelList<Material>(itemList);
lbox.setModel(lm);

ListModelList model = (ListModelList) lbox.getListModel(); // returned type is ListModel<Object> and generates a compiler warning
```

Generates a compiler warning due to cast from ListModel due to type erasure.

But if I do this:

```
ListModelList<Material> lm = new ListModelList<Material>(itemList);
lbox.setModel(lm);

ListModelList<Material> model = lbox.getListModel(); // compiler error.
```

Am I incorrect in thinking that this is an API flaw and requires everyone to do a unsafe cast to the correct generic type (if you even know it) to use generics? Or is there a better way prevent the seemingly needless cast every time?

Comment: Can you post the compiler error mesage from `ListModelList<Material> model = lbox.getListModel();` ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that getListModel() returns a ListModel<T>, and not a ListModelList<T>?

Comment: @PaulBellora The error is: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ListModel<Object> to ListModelList<Material>

Comment: @user2302436 ListModelList is a known implementer of the Interface type ListModel<E> so there shouldn't be any problems with the types and should not need a cast in order to work correctly.

Source: http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/ListModel.html

Comment: @DanielBond Yes, but it is a downcasting and not an upcasting and must be done explicitly, because the interface is ListModel and ListModelList is one of the various classes that implement it. For example the actual ListModel could be a ListModelSet, or another different class implementing ListModel.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. I guess I got a bit confused with the casting and what is expected to need casts and what isn't. It's been a long day so far. 

Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: getListModel() is a generic method so you can use (ListModelList<Material>) lbox.<Material>getListModel() to get back your model of type ListModelList<Material>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getListModel()` returns a `ListModel<T>` and not a `ListModelList<T>`.
So you can replace `ListModelList<Material>` with `ListModel<Material>`, or if you need the methods of `ListModelList` and are sure that this is the type of the object returned, you must do an explicit cast.

```
ListModel<Material> model = lbox.getListModel();
```

or

```
ListModelList<Material> model = (ListModelList<Material>)lbox.getListModel();
```

Comment: ListModel unfortunately does not offer the methods required, as it does not provide an "add(...)" method of any sort and leaves that behaviour to its implementors.
I guess I'm stuck with the casting then for now. 
Thanks for the help.